# for loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, list-comprehension

i would like to turn this for loop into list comprehension

```
people_metrics = []
for idx, user_id in tqdm(enumerate(list(interactions_test_indexed_df.index.unique().values))):
        anime_user_metrics = evaluate_model_for_anime_watcher(model, user_id)  
        anime_user_metrics['_user_id'] = user_id
        people_metrics.append(anime_user_metrics)
    print('%d users processed' % idx)
```

enumerate looks like

```
idx user_id
0      20
1      32
...etc
```

i tried :

```
    anime_user_metrics = [evaluate_model_for_anime_watcher(model, user_id) for idx, user_id in tqdm(np.ndenumerate(list(interactions_test_indexed_df.index.unique().values)))]
```

it work.
then i tried :

```
anime_user_metrics['_user_id']  = list(zip(*enumerate(interactions_test_indexed_df.index.unique().values)))[::-1]
```

or

```
user_proxy = [b for a, b in np.ndenumerate(list(interactions_test_indexed_df.index.unique().values))]
anime_user_metrics['_user_id'] = user_proxy
```

but when i'm tried to do the 2nd line i got an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: `anime_user_metrics` is a list. As the error state `list indices must be integers, not str`. When you do `anime_user_metrics['_user_id']` it then give you the error.

Comment: evaluate_model_for_anime_watcher return a dict, why the for loop works with that line ?

Comment: When you did `anime_user_metrics = [evaluate_model_for_anime_watcher(model, user_id) for idx, user_id in tqdm(np.ndenumerate(list(interactions_test_indexed_df.index.unique().values)))]` you reassigned the dict variable `anime_user_metrics` to a list. That lines works in the for loop because in the for loop it is a dict and dict does not require only ints between the `[]`.
OR I'm just mistaken in your code order. Provide a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get more help from SO community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this because it may be considered hard to read, but one way is to use dict unpacking with `**`

```
v = tqdm(enumerate(list(interactions_test_indexed_df.index.unique().values)))
people_metrics = [
    {**evaluate_model_for_anime_watcher(model, user_id), '_user_id': user_id}
    for idx, user_id in v
]
```

a for loop might just be better in this case

and yes, in your attempt, you define a list `anime_user_metrics` (it's a list because the comprehension is surrounded by `[]`), then try to access values of it by indexing with a string. Lists index with integers. Hence `list indices must be integers, not str`